# SciFi Movie Where Woman Gets her Arm Eaten? Detatched?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, ending

All I can remember is this guy and this woman captured by aliens and her arm somehow got detached (I think it was eaten?) And there was a giant white monster alien thing that they where taken to. The humans wore black (armor, I think?) And the planet/moon whatever was red, if I remember anything correctly.

Also, the white thing kinda looked like a big fat spider, and in the end it was captured and studied. I think it was the alien king? It shot webs from its mouth I think...sorry, I was 7, and this was more than half my life ago so sorry if there is any misinformation! Really hoping to find this!

No idea what time it was made, as it was on TV. Maybe 80s, 90s, early 2000s? This was around 2007-2008.

Comment: Longshot: [Starship Troopers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/)

Comment: Yeah this sounds very Starship Troopers. @John you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 4):

This has several aspects that make it likely this is [**Starship Troopers**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/) (1997)

> And there was a giant white monster alien thing that they were taken to.
>
> Also, the white thing kinda looked like a big fat spider, and in the end it was captured and studied. I think it was the alien king

The Brain Bug is captured by troopers wear **black** armor.

[image]

It's then studied in a lab

> and her arm somehow got detached (I think it was eaten?)

I think you might be conflating this with the dissolving arm sequence.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but the armor looked more grey, and the planet wasn't red.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is it!! I'm amazed that someone was able to decipher this, lol! This brings back so many memories! Thank you!

Comment: Also, the guest, I was 7 so things got muddled, lol

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both answers, it is Starship Trooper. The actress (Denise Richard) did not have her arm detached. She was wounded by the Alien who stabbed her trough the shoulder with his claw.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I remember! This is it! Thank you!